# PHP GET catch all

Tags: php, get, catch-all

Using the GET protocol with php I can get data passed to my program. With something like `$_GET["fname"];`.

What I'm wondering is there any way to make some sort of a catch all. Where I did not need to know the var name before runtime?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. What would you want to do? If you don't care what the name is, then you have to make some assumptions. Are you assuming there's only one GET parameter, and it contains the one value you expect?

Comment: Maybe you want MVC - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just an associative array, handle it like any other:

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

If you just want "the first" value or "the one" value, do:

```
$value = current($_GET);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pull items out of `$_GET` like this:

```
$var = 'fname';
$fname = $_GET[$var];
```

You can pull multiple items like this:

```
foreach(array('fname', 'lname') as $var) {
    echo $var.' = '.$_GET[$var].'<br>;
}
```

Is this what you meant?